# git clone ssh with proxy

Tags: git, ssh

I add this in my ssh `.ssh\config` file:

```
ProxyCommand connect -H http://user:password@myproxy:myproxyport %h %p

Host git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  User myawskey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have this error:

```
$ git push
'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex▒cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
FATAL: Cannot decide password for proxy authentication.kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I fund `connect` bin here:

```
$ connect
connect --- simple relaying command via proxy.
Version 1.105
usage: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\connect.exe [-dnhst45] [-p local-port]
          [-H proxy-server[:port]] [-S [user@]socks-server[:port]]
          [-T proxy-server[:port]]
          [-c telnet-proxy-command]
          host port
```

**EDIT**

I try: `ProxyCommand C:\Program\ Files\Git\mingw64\bin\connect.exe ...`

I try: `ProxyCommand /c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe ...`

I try: `ProxyCommand "/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" ...`

Comment: Please check : https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765#configure-the-proxy

Comment: @dejdej, I looking proxy for `ssh` NOT for `HTTPS`

Comment: Since your `ProxyCommand` contains a space in the first argument you need to quote it to preserve the space: `ProxyCommand "/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" ...`

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I try with, but same error

Comment: Sorry, normally this should solve it:  For `"C:\Program Files"`, use the following path notation `"C:\PROGRA~1"` and for `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` use `"C:\PROGRA~2"`. More info here : https://superuser.com/questions/529400/how-does-progra1-path-notation-work